# Adding a keyword to Code hinting

Tags: dreamweaver

When I add the new JavaScript keyword `async` to my code, Dreamweaver says there is a syntax error and 'code hinting may not work until you fix this error'.

Q: How do I add `async` to the list of approved keywords such that:

```
async function myFunction() {}
```

does not produce a syntax error in Dreamweaver?

Comment: I found your question looking for the same thing.